# How to i use TFS with Visual studio 2010 to simulate multiple users?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, tfs, codeplex

i'm using **VS2010** with **free version of the TFS provided with codeplex**. but i'm only working on one PC. i tried to **simulate** two users by opening two VS and login to TFS from two user names. then when i add a project from source control by **file -> Source control -> Add project from source control** and browse till i find the .sln file, the local path was always the same for two users. it didn't even let me change the local path. because of this when i made changes from one user it made changes to the local solution also it updated solution in codeplex but when i tried to get the latest version from the other user it always said **the local solution was edited and asked to override it**. but i need to update the solution in VS from the server not from the local folder. when i said NO to override then clicked checkout for edit, it never returned the updated version on server. is there away to fix this?

I need to simulate two user using two instances of VS2010. Is there away to do this properly?

thanks

Comment: Sounds like you are trying to test this with a single PC account (despite having two TFS accounts)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You had it right in you post, login using another user, but when you create the local workspace make sure they point to two (2) separate folders.  Don't point the workspaces at the same place on the disk that will not work.

So user A's workspace would be c:\A\source
User B's workspace would be c:\B\source.

All the files will be replicated in both location.  Now if you modify a file in A's workspace and checkin, you'll need to do a get latest from B's VS to it's workspace.

If you modify anything in either workspace you'll need to check it in for the other user to be able to get it their workspace.

Hope this helps,
ET

Answer (score 3):

You can:

1) log out and login as another user
2) use hyper-v locally in Win8+ and spin up another machine
3) spin up a VS trial machene for free in Azure

Comment: Virtualization is a must.  I have an i7-2600k with 32gb memory and SSD drives and it allows me to maintain/checkpoint development environments, host a build controller and have an integration test lab of various machine configurations.  VS Community Edition and VSO is a blessing for a small business like myself.